# Multiple Apks not filtering

Tags: android, screen, android-manifest, google-bigquery, screen-size

so i have an issue wich i have come to a dead end: I am developing an app with 2 apks, one for tablets and one for phones. The thing is, they are separated because the whole application behaves differently when in tablet or phone. My problem begins with the declaration of supported screens, in witch, the tablet manifest shows:

```
<!-- Tablet Screens Only -->
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

The phones manifest does not have any restriction to allow devices that are not filtered this way to be installed with no further inconvinience...

Now, dear samsung released the Samsung MEGA 6.3, with a 6.3 inch screen. This is not getting filtered by the previous supports-screens tag. My first run was to merge both projects into one, but this is not an option as per customers choice. Also bare in mind that bot apps have the same package name and version name, the only difference is the version code.

Comment: How is this related to google-bigquery?